# How many patients has been readmitted within 30 days from their first stay

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

we need to find out how many (and who it is) of our patients who has been  readmitted within 30 days of their first stay.

Table (very simplified): patientID (int), DateInToHospital (datetime), DateOutOfHospital (Datetime).

So we need all patient where DateInToHospital (second stay) <= DateOutOfHospital (first stay) + 30 days

(We use MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Difficult data in this one; I have patients with several stays.
Some stays starts at the same time as last stays ends, so it's not really a new stay.
So far Joel's second solution with CROSS APPLY seems to give the most correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH FirstAdmit AS (
    SELECT patientID, MIN(DateInToHospital) FirstStayStart
    FROM [Table]
), 
FirstDischarge AS (
     SELECT t.patientID, DateOutOfHospital, FirstStayStart
     FROM FirstAdmit a
     INNER JOIN [Table] t ON t.patientID = a.patientID AND t.DateInToHospital = a.FirstStayStart
)
SELECT t.*
FROM [Table] t
INNER JOIN FirstDischarge d on t.patientID = d.patientID 
    AND t.DateInToHospital <= DATEADD(d, 30, d.DateOutOfHospital) 
    AND t.DateInToHospital <> FirstStayStart
```

And here's a version using `APPLY` that might be a bit faster:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM [Table] t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 DateInToHospital, DateOutOfHospital FROM [Table] m WHERE m.patientID = t.patientID ORDER BY DateInToHospital
) FirstStay
WHERE t.DateInToHospital <= DATEADD(d, 30, FirstStay.DateOutOfHospital)
    AND t.DateInToHospital <> FirstStay.DateInToHospital
```

Comment: Both seems to work (after adding GROUP BY patientID after third line in solution 1)
Have to doublecheck before I conclude

Answer (score 1):

This will return the earlier admits of a patient who is re-admitted within 30 days from any admittance:

```
select *
from p
where exists ( /* re-admit within 30 days */
  select 1
  from p i
  where i.PatientId = p.PatientId
    and i.AdmitDate > p.DischargeDate
    and i.AdmitDate <= dateadd(day,30,p.DischargeDate)
    )
```

This will return the initial admittance of a patient who is re-admitted within 30 days from their first admittance:

```
select *
from p
where exists ( /* re-admit within 30 days */
    select 1
    from p i
    where i.PatientId = p.PatientId
      and i.AdmitDate > p.DischargeDate
      and i.AdmitDate <= dateadd(day,30,p.DischargeDate)
      )
  and not exists ( /* only for the first admittance */
    select 1
    from p i
    where i.PatientId = p.PatientId
      and i.AdmitDate < p.AdmitDate
      )
```

Comment: Sorry, I get two patients who are readmitted > 30 days, but readmitted again < 30 days from the second stay.

Comment: @FredMortenSolbakken edited to include `not exists()` clause to only get the first admittance.